# How to display two views block with separate exposed filter respectively in drupal on the same page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-exposed-filter

I am new in drupal. 
I want to display two view block on the same page with different exposed filter respectively.  Please see the image bellow.

[image]

As per the given image View1 and View2 are the different views but View2 is Depend on the View1.

Please Help.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work. Suppose A is the top block and B is the bottom block.

Now, create A block with the exposed filter district. Next, create the B block with the two exposed filters for district and Census. Make sure the identifier in the B block for the district exposed filter should be same as on A block. So whatever value you applied in A block will also filter the result of the B block with the same filter criteria. Show both on a page by assigning them in a region from here in admin `/admin/structure/block`. Now, you can hide the district field of the B block using the CSS.

You can also look at the [Views Field Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module to help you to achieve the same with other way.

Comment: Thanks for Answer, But as i read on forum Exposed Filter is only work with view page.  is there any other solution Please..

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_filter_block use this module for the same ability with view blocks

Comment: Two different Exposed filter are displayed but the value of Exposed form one (district) and the Exposed form two (district) are not change as per First value